# customHooks module.exports not importing with es6 style

Tags: node.js, reactjs, import, importerror, module.exports

I have an app that I ran this same architecture and it works no problem. I am trying to duplicate in a CRA with React 17.0.2. This is just a file that holds my custom hooks in an organized fashion using `module.exports`. Here is my file: *customHooks.js*

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

module.exports = {
    usePrevious: (stateValue) => {
        const ref = useRef();
        useEffect(() => {
            ref.current = stateValue;
        })
        return ref.current
    },
    getUrlVars: (url) => {
        let vars = {};
        if (url) {
            let parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
                vars[key] = value;
            });
        } else {
            console.error('No url specified')
        }

        return vars;
    },
    setCookieManually: async (cname, cvalue, exdays) => {
        const d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    },
    removeCookieManually: async (cname) => {
        document.cookie = `${cname}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;`
    },
    useSetState: (initialValue) => {
        let [val, setVal] = useState(initialValue);
        let cbRef = useRef(null);
        let first = useRef(true);

        useEffect(() => {
            if (first.current) {
                first.current = false;
                return;
            }

            if (typeof cbRef.current === "function") {
                console.log("calling cb");
                cbRef.current();
            }
        }, [val]);

        let setValCB = useCallback((newVal, cb) => {
            console.log("setValCB", newVal);
            cbRef.current = cb;
            setVal(newVal);
        }, []);

        /*
        * USAGE:
        * let [selected, setSelected] = useSetState("");
        *
        * setSelected(title, () => {
        *   console.log("onRowSelected", title);
        *   props.onRowSelected(title);
        * });
        *
        * */

        return [val, setValCB];
    }
}
```

I am just trying to import like this:

```js
import { usePrevious } from '..customHooks'
```

Yet I keep getting an error: `Attempted import error: 'usePrevious' is not exported from '../customHooks.js'`.

Note: I have done this successfully with a NextJs project no problem.

- Is there something that my IDE doesn't like?
- Is it **Bable**?

Let me know what you think the issue is.

I have tried to change it from `import` to `require()` and it resolves the error but then says:
`TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

What does this mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Update: Node Version 14 and after may run into this problem

---

To solve this issue the `module.exports` had to be removed. Seems after node 14 things get weird with it.

Now I had to write out each function then `export` that function in structure.

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

   const usePrevious = (stateValue) => {
        const ref = useRef();
        useEffect(() => {
            ref.current = stateValue;
        })
        return ref.current
    }

   const getUrlVars = (url) => {
        let vars = {};
        if (url) {
            let parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
                vars[key] = value;
            });
        } else {
            console.error('No url specified')
        }

        return vars;
    }

   const setCookieManually = async (cname, cvalue, exdays) => {
        const d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

   const removeCookieManually = async (cname) => {
        document.cookie = `${cname}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;`
    }

   const useSetState = (initialValue) => {
        let [val, setVal] = useState(initialValue);
        let cbRef = useRef(null);
        let first = useRef(true);

        useEffect(() => {
            if (first.current) {
                first.current = false;
                return;
            }

            if (typeof cbRef.current === "function") {
                console.log("calling cb");
                cbRef.current();
            }
        }, [val]);

        let setValCB = useCallback((newVal, cb) => {
            console.log("setValCB", newVal);
            cbRef.current = cb;
            setVal(newVal);
        }, []);

        /*
        * USAGE:
        * let [selected, setSelected] = useSetState("");
        *
        * setSelected(title, () => {
        *   console.log("onRowSelected", title);
        *   props.onRowSelected(title);
        * });
        *
        * */

        return [val, setValCB];
    }

export {
    usePrevious,
    getUrlVars,
    setCookieManually,
    removeCookieManually,
    useSetState,
}
```

This then allowed all my imports to work with the destructuring:

```js
import { usePrevious } from '../utils/customHooks'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with default import instead of named? because the file you are exporting is not a named export, but a default.

So you can try this,

```
import usePrevious from '..customHooks'
```

Comment: Yep, and it doesn't work. This is something weird with the project I assume. If I delete the destructuring it throws an `undefined` error.